# SQL query to get count of unique combinations in the table - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mapping table like below

```
c1  c2
--  --
1   1
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   1
```

and so on. The table has a separate id column (not showed here).
Here is my query so far :

```
SELECT `c1`, `c2`, COUNT(*) AS `count_of_uniques` FROM `map_table` 
GROUP BY `c1`, `c2`
```

I have also tried with distinct query like this.

```
SELECT `c1`, `c2`, COUNT(DISTINCT `c1`, `c2`) AS `count_of_uniques` FROM `map_table`
```

The expected result is

```
c1  c2  count_of_uniques
--  --  ----------------
1   1   2
1   2   2
1   3   3
2   2   1
2   3   1
```

My current query shows the correct output when the combination is made of two similar numbers, but when we have something like 1-2 and 2-1, the query does not have the correct output.

distinct shows still fewer results.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your expected output [exactly matches](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c0b6432f881d1fbe6746a3efad13179) the actual output of your first query. Have you posted the wrong expected output?

Comment: is it SQL or MySQL?

Comment: *"is it SQL or MySQL?"* @Sirmyself the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag is not about SQL Server (MSSQL) on this website if that is what you are thinking..

Comment: @raymond-nijland I stand corrected then

Comment: @GarethD I am sorry for the wrong data. I tried to make thinds simple but loosing lot of detail. [Here is the actual problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8ce0ffba7a58bc6e74d3bd83de8cdb4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you might be after something that deals with combinations rather than permutations i.e `1, 2` and `2, 1` should be treated as the same combination. If this is the case you can use a case expression to make sure that c1 is always the lower of the two values, and c2 is the higher of the two. This will group similar pairs together (so `2, 1` will first be reversed to become `1, 2` then grouped with all similar results):

```
SELECT c1, c2, COUNT(*) AS `count_of_uniques` 
FROM (  SELECT CASE WHEN c1 > c2 THEN c2 ELSE c1 END AS c1, 
                CASE WHEN c1 > c2 THEN c1 ELSE c2 END AS c2
        FROM map_table) AS t
GROUP BY c1, c2
```

**Output**

```
c1      c2      count_of_uniques
-------------------------------
1       1       2
1       2       2
1       3       3
2       2       1
2       3       1
```

**[Example on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cea110adef19eb9d0c056a77e00d06ac)**

Comment: Best answer I think. Question though: what would be more efficient between using the `IF` function and using the `CASE` statement?

Comment: The question shows a case *expression*, not a case statement (the difference is often me being pedantic, but in MySQL it is more important as MySQL has both a [case statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) and a [case expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)). Nonetheless, [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527259) and there was no conclusive answer. Realistically I would expect any performance difference to be so negligible they can assumed to be equal.

Comment: I know SQL Server a lot better than MySQL and I know the SQL Server equivalent to `IF()` (`IIF()`) is rewritten during compilation as a CASE expression anyway, so there is absolutely zero performance difference. I would expect MySQL to take advance of a similar operation, so that internally both are performing exactly the same operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions [`least()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`greatest()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to get the pairs on which you will group:

```
select 
  least(c1, c2) c1, 
  greatest(c1, c2) c2, 
  count(*) count_of_uniques
from map_table  
group by 
  least(c1, c2), 
  greatest(c1, c2)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xxRwpq8qRpLKAsZr3iUaWd/0).
Results:

```
| c1  | c2  | count_of_uniques |
| --- | --- | ---------------- |
| 1   | 1   | 2                |
| 1   | 2   | 2                |
| 1   | 3   | 3                |
| 2   | 2   | 1                |
| 2   | 3   | 1                |
```

Answer (score 0):

Select C1,C2,Count(*) from map_table Group By C1,C2 Order by C1